# How to release resources from a Preference, an equivalent to onDestroy() available?

Tags: android, admob

Android has a nicely defined lifecycle for its Activities: it starts with onCreate() and ends with its destruction with a call to onDestroy(). I'm trying to find something similar for my custom [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) objects that are managed in a [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), i.e.: I want to be able to destroy the resources that I created during the Preference's onCreateView() when the Preference is end of life. Is there a proper way of doing this without having to define a public destroy() function in the custom Preference and then calling this from the onDestroy() function of the PreferenceFragment?

E.g.:

- the onDestroy() function of the PreferenceFragment:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

      AdMobPreference admobPref1 = (AdMobPreference) this.findPreference("admob1");
      admobPref1.destroy();
      AdMobPreference admobPref2 = (AdMobPreference) this.findPreference("admob2");
      admobPref2.destroy();

      Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called!");
  }
  ```
- the destroy() function of the AdMobPreference (custom preference)

  ```
  public void destroy() {
      if(mAdView != null) {
          mAdView.destroy();
          mAdView = null;
      }
  }
  ```

This quickly shows that there is some high coupling between the xml that defines the custom Preference (since we need to define explicit keys, admob1 and admob2 in this case) and the sourcecode of the PreferenceFragment (a specific destroy() instruction needs to be added to the onDestroy() function, e.g.: admobPref1.destroy(); in this case).
I would assume that Google would have anticipated this kind of situation and that a Preference might need a proper overrideable onDestroy() to clean up resources? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right solution is to use a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). A Fragment has a its own lifecycle, so resources can be correctly managed.

The added value of using a Fragment to show the AdMob banner, is the possibility to split up the settings screen in 2: the AdMob Fragment on top and the PreferenceFragment underneath it.
Another positive point: issues with AdMob compliancy have been solved this way: only 1 banner on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Well I suspect that the design of Preferences was tightly focused around .. Preferences.

They certainly didn't expect you to be attempting to serve ads in your preference screen.

Can I just note that:

1. You are highly unlikely to get any significant ad traffic from ads displayed on a pref screen.
2. It is against Admob policy for you to show more than one banner ad on a screen.

Answer (score -1):

There's no `onDestory()` or any other lifecycle method. So you have to build your own. Here's my code:

On custom preference:

```
public class SetTimeoutPreference extends Preference {
...

public void bind(Context context){
...
}

public void unbind(Context context){
...
}
}
```

On Activity:

```
private SetTimeoutPreference mTimeoutPreference;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mTimeoutPreference = mPrefsFragment.getPreference(PREF_SET_TIMEOUT);
    mTimeoutPreference.onBind(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); 
    mTimeoutPreference.onUnbind();
}
```

`getPreference()` on the PreferenceFragment is:

```
public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    public <T extends Preference> T getPreference(CharSequence key) {
        return (T) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(key);
    }
}
```

Note that the `onCreateView()` of Preference may be called after activity's `onResume()` so it's not safe to initialize variable in it.